# How to add date in ArrayList of "Date" data type?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Assume

```
List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

how to add the user date in the above `date` object?

Comment: `date.add(user.date);`

Comment: What's `Date`? A custom class you've written? An arbitrary object type to signify what you're looking for? In the latter case you want [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: Do you want to just add the current date to the list? Question is a bit vague. If so `date.add(new Date())`

Comment: No, Date is a default class.

Comment: Acutally I want to add N number of different date in list, then I need to sort the date, according to the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
date.add(new Date());
```

ez

or

```
date.add(user.getDate());
```